# align trapezium in cirtuit tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, circuitikz

Here is the code of what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}%to draw
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,petri}
\usepackage{circuitikz}%para dibujos con pouertas logicas etc
\usepackage{pgfplots}%graficas en tikz
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\patitas{2}%distance for patitas de las puertas lógicas etc
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US,
                tiny circuit symbols,
                every circuit symbol/.style={fill=white,draw, logic gate input sep=1mm},
node distance = 1cm,
]


\tikzset{font=\scriptsize}
%logic gate nodes

\node[and gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at ($(1,0.5)$) (andpriman) {}; 
\node[and gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] [above of =andpriman] (andprima1) {};
\node[and gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] [node distance=1cm,above of =andprima1] (andn) {};
\node[and gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] [above of =andn] (and1) {}; 

\path ([yshift=-1mm]and1.south) -- (andn.north) node [black, font=\Large, midway, sloped] (vdots1) {$\dots$};    
\path ([yshift=-1mm]andprima1.south) -- (andpriman.north) node [black, font=\Large, midway, sloped] (vdots2) {$\dots$}; 

\node[or gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] [right of =vdots1] (orexcitatorias) {}; 
\node[nor gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] [right of =vdots2] (norinhibitorias) {}; 
\node at ($ (orexcitatorias) !.5! (norinhibitorias) $) (aux1) {}; 
\node[and gate, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] [right of =aux1]  (andgatherer) {};  

    \draw (andpriman.input 1) -- ++(left:\patitas mm) node[yshift=1mm, left=0mm] (xpriman) {$x'_{n'}$};
\draw (andpriman.input 2) -- ++(left:\patitas mm) node[yshift=-1mm, left=0mm] (wprimajn) {$i_{n'}$};
\draw (andprima1.input 1) -- ++(left:\patitas mm) node[yshift=1mm, left=0mm] (xpriman) {$x'_1$};
\draw (andprima1.input 2) -- ++(left:\patitas mm) node[yshift=-1mm, left=0mm] (wprimajn) {$i_1$};
\draw (andn.input 1) -- ++(left:\patitas mm) node[yshift=1mm, left=0mm] (xpriman) {$x_n$};
\draw (andn.input 2) -- ++(left:\patitas mm) node[yshift=-1mm, left=0mm] (wprimajn) {$e_n$};                \draw (and1.input 1) -- ++(left:\patitas mm) node[yshift=1mm, left=0mm] (xpriman) {$x_1$};
\draw (and1.input 2) -- ++(left:\patitas mm) node[yshift=-1mm, left=0mm] (wprimajn) {$e_1$};

\draw (and1.output) -- ++(right:\patitas mm) node [midway, right, blue] {$x_1 \cap e_1$} |- (orexcitatorias.input 1);
\draw (andn.output) -- ++(right:\patitas mm) node [midway, right, blue] {$x_n \cap e_n$} |- (orexcitatorias.input 2);
\draw (andprima1.output) -- ++(right:\patitas mm) node [midway, right, blue] {$x'_1 \cap i_1$} |- (norinhibitorias.input 1);
\draw (andpriman.output) -- ++(right:\patitas mm) node [midway, right, blue] {$x'_{n'} \cap i_{n'}$} |- (norinhibitorias.input 2);
\draw (orexcitatorias.output) -- ++(right:\patitas mm) node [midway, right, blue] {$\cup \left(x_i \cap e_i\right)$} |- (andgatherer.input 1);
\draw (norinhibitorias.output) -- ++(right:\patitas mm) node [midway, right, blue] {$\cup \left(x'_i \cap i_i\right)$} |- (andgatherer.input 2);



\node at ($ (orexcitatorias) !.5! (andgatherer)$) (aux2) {}; 
\node [trapezium, draw,minimum width=0.5cm,
trapezium left angle=65, trapezium right angle=65, rotate=270] [node distance=2cm,above of =aux2]  (addernode) {\small Adder}; 


\draw (andgatherer.output) -- ++(right:\patitas mm) node [midway,right,blue] {$E_n$} |- (addernode.south east);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: here is the output of such code]

What I want is to place the adder trapecium in a way such that the line joining the and gate's output with the adder is always perpendicular.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try with `\node [trapezium, draw,minimum width=0.5cm,
trapezium left angle=65, trapezium right angle=65, rotate=270] [node distance=1cm,above of = andgatherer]  (addernode) {\small Adder};`?

Comment: You're using the deprecated `above of=` syntax, I think you should try to understand and use the new `positioning` library. (see pgfmanual section: 17.5.3 Advanced Placement Options)

Comment: The example you tell in the first comment would not place the node where I need it to be placed. I will read the pgf manual section you told me in the second comment to see if I can figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Then I undersrand that you want the adder where it is but with an straight line from the and output to the adder's border. If it's like this, don't move the adder and draw a line with: `\draw (andgatherer.output)--(andgatherer.output-|addernode.west);`

Comment: Here is the best solution I have found:  `\node[draw,trapezium, draw,trapezium left angle=65, trapezium right angle=65, rotate=270,anchor=south east] at ($(andgatherer)+(1.5*\nd,0)$) (addernode) {Adder}`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the command

```
\draw (andgatherer.output)
   -- ++(right:\patitas mm) node [midway,right,blue,below] {$E_n$}
   -- (andgatherer-|addernode.south);
```

`addernode.south` is a point on the *base line* of the trapezium. Since the trapezium is rotated, this point marks the left border of the trapezium after rotation. `(andgatherer-|addernode.south)` denotes the point where a horizontal line from `andgatherer` meets a vertical line coming down from `addernode.south`. Which is exactly the point where the straight line from `andgatherer` should end.

Here is a suggestion how your code can be simplified using `ciruitikz`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw
    (0,6) node[and port] (and1) {}
    (0,4) node[and port] (and2) {}
    (0,2) node[and port] (and3) {}
    (0,0) node[and port] (and4) {}
    (3,5) node[or  port] (or1)  {}
    (3,1) node[nor port] (nor1) {}
    (5,3) node[and port] (and5) {}
    (6,3.5) node [trapezium, draw,minimum width=0.5cm,
                  trapezium left angle=65,trapezium right angle=65,
                  rotate=270,thick] (adder) {\small adder}
    (and1.out) node[right]{$x_1\cap e_1$}              |- (or1.in 1)
    (and2.out) node[right]{$x_n\cap e_n$}              |- (or1.in 2)
    (and3.out) node[right]{$x'_1\cap i_1$}             |- (nor1.in 1)
    (and4.out) node[right]{$x'_{n'}\cap i_{n'}$}       |- (nor1.in 2)
    (or1.out)  node[right]{$\bigcup_i (x_i\cap e_i)$}  |- (and5.in 1)
    (nor1.out) node[right]{$\bigcup_i (x'_i\cap i_i)$} |- (and5.in 2)
    (and5.out) node[below]{$E_n$}                      -- (and5.out-|adder.south)
    (adder.north) to [short,-o] +(0.5,0)
    \foreach \p/\l in
      {and1.in 1/{x_1},and1.in 2/e_1,
       and2.in 1/x_n,and2.in 2/e_n,
       and3.in 1/x'_1,and3.in 2/i_1,
       and4.in 1/x'_{n'},and4.in 2/i_{n'}%
      } 
      {([xshift=-0.5cm]\p) node[left]{$\l$} to [short,o-]  (\p)}
    ;
  \draw[loosely dotted,very thick]
    (-0.5,4.6) -- (-0.5,5.4)
    (-0.5,0.6) -- (-0.5,1.4)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```